# Prove the norm $|||u||| = \|u\|_p +\|u\|_q$ is equivalent to $W^{1,p}$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $I$ be bounded interval.Let $u \in W^{1,p}(I)$ for $1\le p\le \infty$ for any $q\in[1,\infty]$ prove that $W^{1,p} $norm are equivalent to $$|||u||| = \|u'\|_p + \|u\|_q$$

My attempt: first $\|u\|_{W^{1,p}} = (\|u\|_p^p+\|u'\|_p^{p})^{1/p}$ then it equivlalent to $\|u\|_p +\|u'\|_p$ by Holder inequality for $\ell_p$.

Secondly,we use Sobolev embedding $\|u\|_\infty\le C(\|u\|_p+\|u'\|_p)$. for any $q$,we have $\|u\|_q \le C\|u\|_\infty \le C'(\|u\|_p +\|u'\|_p)$ hence $|||u|||\le C(\|u\|_p +\|u'\|_p)$

Only need to prove the inequality $\|u\|_{W^{1,p}}\le C|||u|||$ then

To do this $$u(t)- u(t_0) = \int^t_{t_0}u'(t)dt$$

then $$|u(t)|-|u(t_0)|\le |\int^{t}_{t_0}u'(t)dt|\le \|u'\|_1$$

Hence $$|u(t)| \le \|u'\|_1 + |u(t_0)|$$ for all $t\in I$

So we have $\|u\|_\infty\le \|u'\|_1 + |u(t_0)|$

Finally integrate over $t_0$ we have $$|I|\|u\|_\infty \le |I|\|u'\|_1 + \|u\|_1$$

If $|I| \ne 0$ we can see $\|u\|_p \le C'\|u\|_\infty \le C(\|u\|_1 + \|u'\|_1)\le C|||u|||$

As daw's post shows we can only change the norm for zero order $u$ .

For $\|u'\|_q$ needs not to be bounded.

Comment: How do you know that $\lVert u' \rVert_q < \infty$?

Comment: @Meowdog Sorry for that it's a typo edit.My attempt is based on $|||u||| = \|u'\|_p + \|u\|_q$

Comment: The 'wlog $u(x_0)=0$' loses generality. What if $u$ is strictly positive?

Comment: For the missing direction, try to prove $\|u\|_{L^\infty}\le c \|u\|_{W^{1,1}}\le c' |||u|||$.

Comment: @daw thanks for your hint ,is my corrected solution correct?

Comment: yes, looks good now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is clearly false:

If $q>p$ then there are functions in $u\in W^{1,p}$ such that $u'\not\in L^q$, so $|||u|||=+\infty$, but $\|u\|_{W^{1,p}}<+\infty$. (To construct $u$ take $v\in L^q\setminus L^p$ and set $u(x)=\int_0^x v(s)ds$).

If $q<p$: Take $u\in W^{1,q} \setminus W^{1,p}$. Approximate $u$ by smooth functions $u_k \in C_c^\infty$ such that $u_k \to u$ in $W^{1,q}$. Then $\|u_k\|_{W^{1,q}} \to \|u\|_{W^{1,q}}$ buut $\|u_k\|_{W^{1,p}}\to\infty$.

What would work is if $|||\cdot|||$ would be defined as $\|u\|_{L^q} + \|u'\|_{L^p}$.